# Are wh-words conjunctions when they begin a dependent (wh-) clause?

Tags: conjunctions, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, dependent-clause

According to "A glossary of English Grammar" by Goeffrey Leech:

> "The **wh-words** are: who, whom, whose, which, what, how, when, where, why."

In the paragraph where Leech defines the term conjunction he gives some examples of subordinating conjunctions:

> "In practice, 'conjunction' refers to two rather different classes of words: coordinating conjunctions (and, or, but and sometimes nor) and **subordinating conjunctions (if, when, because, and so on)**"

In the following example sentences, the subordinate clauses in square brackets begin with wh-words. **Are the wh-words (what, where, when, which), which begin the subordinate clauses, conjunctions or not? Or can they be considered as conjunctions?**

1. [***What*** you do] does not concern me.
2. I didn't ask [***where*** you live]
3. I’ll phone you [***when*** I arrive].
4. She told me a story [**which** made me laugh out loud]

Edit:

In "Practical English Usage", the author Michael Swan uses the term "Interrogative conjunctions":

> Interrogative conjunctions like *who, which, what, where, whether* can
>   follow prepositions.
>
> -We discussed the question of [**who** to appoint as manager].
>
> -I may be able to come: it depends on [**which** day you are holding the meeting].
>
> -They were not at all interested in [**what** I thought].

Comment: Are you suggesting that they should be called 'informative conjunctions' ?